# How to Animate one FBX model from another FBX animation using C# script in Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, automation, fbx

I'm new to Unity and it may be a basic information.

I want to animate a FBX model from another FBX model animation.
For example, We have A_FBX and B_FBX files.
*A_FBX has model and without animation.
*B_FBX has model and animation

I have to animate A_FBX model with B_FBX animation with C# program only. 
And there should not be any manual steps. Everything through C# code only.

Tried following code, but didn't work. It has some manual work that is we will map the each game object properties with A_FBX and B_FBX.

```
Animation anim;
  //obj1 is GameObject and it will be mapped to A_FBX
  anim = obj1.AddComponent<Animation>();
//obj1 is GameObject and it will be mapped to A_FBX
  anim = obj2.GetComponent<Animation>();

  anim.Play();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both models the-same?

Comment: Yes. Both are humanoid models only. 
I'm able assign the one FBX animation other manually in Animation window. But, want to do it through C# coding.

Comment: I want to read animation data from one model and feed the same into another FBX model using c# script only.

Comment: I know what you want to do. You have not answered my first question. I didn't ask anything about humanoid

Comment: Both are different models.

Comment: See [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html)

Comment: Thanks for this info and it is helpful. 

I need one more clarification. 
It is possible do the animation just through coding only instead animator controller ?

why I'm asking this is, If I have multiple FBX animation files. It has only animations. is it possible to read FBX animation data via coding and feed to another model ? 

If any example related to this scenario, let me know.